# Getting redirected when refreshed emberjs

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-router

My `router.js` is like this:

```
// router.js
this.route('cards', function() {
  this.route('all');
  this.route('card', {path: '/:card_id'}, function() {
    this.route('edit');
  });
  this.route('new');
});
```

Now, suppose, I'm inside this link: `/cards/1`. When I refresh this page, I go to the route `/cards/all`.

I'm redirecting to `/cards/all` from `/cards`:

```
// cards.js
beforeModel() {
  this.transitionTo('cards.all');
}
```

Why am I getting redirected to `/cards/all` when I refresh in `/cards/1`?

Repo link: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are transitioned to `/cards/all` because the route `/cards/:card_id` is nested into `/cards` route so when you enter the `/cards/:card_id` route the order of execution is:

- `cards` route (beforeModel, model, ...)
- `cards/:id` route (beforeModel, model, ...)

But in cards route beforeModel you are transitioning to `cards.all`, that's why the redirect.